# Accessing the root directory from an npm grunt task

Tags: node.js, task, gruntjs

I'm writing a grunt task which will eventually be available over npm. I'm struggling with how I can get it to read files (specifically `bower.json`) in the project's root directory when it's included as a dependency. I'm using tried `../../../bower.json` at the moment, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to obtain the root directory than manually traversing up the directory tree?

*edit `require('../../../bower.json')` but `fs.readFile('./bower.json' ... )` are what work for me